# How to toggle table contents with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-table

I have a button, when I click it the tables `td`'s must be empty, on second click they must be filled again.
Problem is, when I use `.empty()` it leaves the table empty and I can't restore the values.

`.hide()` and `.show()` only works with html elements, they cant hide/show content.

`.html()` and `.text()` selects the content but I can't find the way to toggle them.

jQuery code:

```
$('#totalsTable tbody').on('click', 'td.details-control', function () {
    var tr = $(this).closest('tr');
    var row = totalsTable.row(tr);
    if (row.child.isShown()) {
        $('#totalsTable .active td:nth-child(6), .active td:nth-child(3), .active td:nth-child(4), .active td:nth-child(5)').html().show();
    } else {
       $('#totalsTable .active td:nth-child(6), .active td:nth-child(3), .active td:nth-child(4), .active td:nth-child(5)').html().hide();
    }
});
```

**HTML**

```
<table id="totalsTable" class="table table-bordered small table-hover" width="100%">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th></th>
            <th>#{label['regress.totals']}</th>
            <th>#{label['regress.description']}</th>
            <th>#{label['regress.totals.debt']}</th>
            <th>#{label['regress.totals.paid']}</th>
            <th>#{label['regress.totals.debt']}<i class="fa fa-plus text-success" />#{label['regress.totals.overpay']}<i class="fa fa-minus text-danger" />
            </th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td>#{label['regress.totals.main-total']}</td>
            <td>Kelių žodžių komentaras</td>
            <td>3478 Eur</td>
            <td>478 Eur</td>
            <td class="text-success">3000 Eur</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="active">
            <td class="details-control"></td>
            <th>#{label['regress.totals.extra-totals']}</th>
            <td>Kelių žodžių komentaras</td>
            <td>3478 Eur</td>
            <td>4000 Eur</td>
            <td class="text-danger">-522 Eur</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="extra" hidden="true">
            <td></td>
            <td><a href="#">Už žalų administravimą </a>
            </td>
            <td>Kelių žodžių komentaras</td>
            <td><a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#paymentInfo">200 Eur</a>
            </td>
            <td>120 Eur</td>
            <td class='text-success'>80 Eur</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="extra" hidden="true">
            <td></td>
            <td><a href="#">Bylinėjimo išlaidos </a>
            </td>
            <td>Kelių žodžių komentaras</td>
            <td><a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#paymentInfo">200 Eur</a>
            </td>
            <td>120 Eur</td>
            <td class='text-success'>80 Eur</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="extra" hidden="true">
            <td></td>
            <td><a href="#">Bylinėjimo išlaidos </a>
            </td>
            <td>Kelių žodžių komentaras</td>
            <td><a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#paymentInfo">200 Eur</a>
            </td>
            <td>120 Eur</td>
            <td class='text-success'>80 Eur</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
    <tfoot>
        <tr>
            <th></th>
            <th colspan="2" style="text-align:right">#{label['regress.total-sum']}</th>
            <th>6956 Eur</th>
            <th>4478 Eur</th>
            <th class="text-success">2478 Eur</th>
        </tr>
    </tfoot>
</table>
```

Comment: Please provide some HTML.

Comment: Does the above code works with `.empty()`?

Comment: .empty() does remove the values, but i can't show them after another click

Comment: why dont you place your content inside a span and show/hide those spans?

Comment: @ManuelReis I was about to upvote your answer as using storing at render time is a useful option to this problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Once you use `.empty()`, it deletes the content (by *empty*ing it).  The contents cannot be restored because it's been deleted.

You can get around this by adding an inner element and `show` / `hide` that, eg:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td><div>content</div></td>
```

then

```
$("table td:nth-child(0) > div,table td:nth-child(6) > div").hide();
```

or, you can *store* the existing value before removing it, eg:

```
$("table td:nth-child(0)").each(function() {
  $(this).data($(this).html());
  $(this).html("");
});
```

then, to restore:

```
$("table td:nth-child(0)").each(function() {
  $(this).html($(this).data("store"));
});
```

Note, you need to use `.each` as each element's value in the selector needs to store its own value.

Answer (score 1):

Do something like this

```
// Selecting all elements
$el = $('#totalsTable .active td:nth-child(6), .active td:nth-child(3), .active td:nth-child(4), .active td:nth-child(5)');
if (row.child.isShown()) {
    $el.each(function () {

        // Setting HTML from data-val
        $(this).html($(this).data("val"));

    });
} else {

    $el.each(function () {

        // Setting data-val equals to html which can be used later and emptying the html 
        $(this).data("val", $(this).html());
        $(this).html("");
    });
}
```

Comment: @freedomn-m You need `.html("")` to empty the html

Answer (score 1):

I see others have now answered with what are most probably better solutions, but here is a fiddle I made in case it helps: https://jsfiddle.net/w81qtgp2/

```
$('table').click(function () {

    $(this).children().each(function () {
        if ($(this).html() === '<td> </td>') {
            $(this).html($(this).data('text'));
        } else {
            var tdText = ($(this).html());
            $(this).data('text', tdText);
            $(this).html('<td> </td>');
        }
    });
});
```